# Setting CPM-Targets in facebooks monetization manager

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-monetization-manager

Is it possible to set the CPM-Target inside the monetization manager with the graph api?

[image: UI CPM-Target inside the monetization manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the facebook support and got the following response:

> Hi Pascal,
>
> sorry for the delay, needed to clarify this first  - unfortunately, as
>   of now, it's not possible to set CPM targets via the api.
>
> Regards,